# I am trying to parse an XML document but keep getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to parse an XML document but keep getting org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
    <to>Jamie</to>
    <from>Michelle</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget about me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Code

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream( "any/TextUtilsTest_test_parseDocument.xml".getBytes() );
XmlUtils.parseDocument(is), document);

    public static Document parseDocument( byte[] bytes, Schema schema, boolean caretAware ) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        try (ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( bytes )) {
            return parseDocument( inputStream, schema, caretAware );
        }
    }

public static Document parseDocument( InputStream inputStream, Schema schema, boolean caretAware ) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException, SAXException {
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = XmlUtils.createDocumentBuilderFactory();

        factory.setNamespaceAware( schema != null );
        if (schema != null) {
            factory.setSchema( schema );
        }

        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        documentBuilder.setErrorHandler( new DefaultErrorHandler( true ) );

        if (caretAware) {
            DOMParser domParser = getDOMParser( documentBuilder );
            if (domParser != null) {
                XMLParserConfiguration configuration = domParser.getXMLParserConfiguration();
                configuration.setDocumentHandler( new CaretAwareDocumentHandler( configuration.getDocumentHandler(), domParser ) );
                configuration.setFeature( Constants.XERCES_FEATURE_PREFIX + Constants.DEFER_NODE_EXPANSION_FEATURE, false );
            }
        }
        return documentBuilder.parse( inputStream );
    }
```

I'm not sure where the problem arises

Comment: It just might be there is an invisible zero-width BOM character at the first position of the XML file. This is redundant and illegal in XML, as not considered whitespace like spaces or tabs.. Remove `<` and more to the left, and retype '<''. Then it might run. Check the file lengths before and after.

Comment: Or could d be you are not parsing the XML content but erroneously the file path "any/TextUtilsTest_tes..." as XML.

Comment: Looks like it's the second suggestion